# String Comparison Issue with xml and php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a problem with xml in php... when I say `echo $meta2->nodeValue;` It shows Address but when I say `if ($meta2->nodeValue=="Address"){echo $meta2->nodeValue;}` it does not show anything... Any ideas? nodeType=1

Comment: Do a `var_dump($meta2->nodeValue)` to see what's really inside

Comment: Depends on what 'it shows' means. Any non-visible symbol may happily belong to `nodeValue`, yet, of course, its non-visibility won't be taken into account by PHP when comparing these strings.

Comment: yes but how do i find that non-visible symbol?

Comment: var_dump($meta2->nodeValue) shows string 'Address

' (length=9)
there is a line break after Address_ (_ = space)

Comment: Try typecasting the nodeValue to a string: if ( "Address" == (string) $meta2->nodeValue ) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trim the value to be sure to avoid all non-visible character:

```
if (rtrim($meta2->nodeValue) == "Address")
{
  echo $meta2->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Ain't it what happens _in this_ case behind the curtain when PHP parses `==` - and sees that one operand is a string? )